# Multiple points openlayers geojson display only the last of it

Tags: javascript, location

I made a module retrieving data with geodata. The import feature allows to create a file in geojson. So, i'd like to display the points and the data without using Views, only openlayers module. 
I saw the layer example provided with the module : *Example GeoJSON, "Picture This"*, displaying a marker with the given raw geojson data provided.
In the Layer section, I tried to use the URL field instead of the raw data field to provide a link to my datafile, but when i use it on a map, only the last point is displayed.

I saw that in the example :

```
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "name": "Picture This",
      "description": "Outside of the North Carolina Museum of Art."
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
        -78.702798,
        35.809411
      ]
    },
    "crs": {
      "type": "name",
      "properties": {
          "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
      }
    }
  }
```

but the "regular"geojson is a collection of such features :

```
{ "type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {"name": "point1", "description": "desc of 1"},
        "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-78, 35]
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {"name": "point2", "description": "desc of 2"},
        "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-79, 34]
        }
      }
]}
```

So, since i have more than 1 point i used the second version, and i only get the last point showing when i use this overlay on a map.

Is there something special to do to display several point or shapes (from a layer) using that technique : i'd like to avoid using Views or any other plugins for this.

I've read https://www.drupal.org/node/1481374 and other generic openlayer Drupal 7 tutorials, but i haven't found any help for this kind of problem.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i found out that the problems (only the last point and that point wasn't at the right place) had nothing to do with my geojson file : i created a new layer and by default it had projection **EPSG:3857**, but i needed a projection with GPS coordinates => **EPSG:4326** see [this](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84/) . With that change, every point is now displayed. I guess with the wrong projection, all the points where somehow stacked, and then only the last one was displayable.

In Openlayer > Layers

- Use Projection EPSG:4326 (instead of EPSG:3857)

In Openlayer > Map 
Use

- Map Projection EPSG:3857 (Default)
- Display Projection EPSG:4326(Default)